# ERRNO 22 - Python - Invalid argument - why is this path causing an error in my error handling script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that syncs my files from my linux machine to an external HDD . All works fine but it gets stuck on this line.

```
[*INFO]| 2020.11.22D12.21.06.646485| createPath: Directory doesn't exists. Creating /media/genericUser/5A48F86048F83BF7/2020.11.22/crtFolder/2020/udemy/react/code/section_12_adding_routing_someApp/addinRouting/src/hoc/Aux/
```

Here's the code:

```
def createPath(src, root,dest, dV,file):
    #if the destination doesn't have / add it
    if(dest[-1] != "/"):
        log(0,"createPath: Adding / to " + dest,file)
        dest = dest + "/"
    #Create the path to be created
    dest = dest + root.split(src)[-1] + "/"
    if(not os.path.exists(dest)):
        if dV['VERBOSE']:
            log(0,"createPath: Directory doesn't exists. Creating " + dest,file)
        try:
            os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
            return dest
        except OSError as e:
            log(1,"createPath: Failed to create " + dest + " with error " + e,file)  
    else:
        return dest
```

Full error output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/genericUser/cf35aee0-faeb-40bb-adac-88595e8f71fe/genericUser_hdd/crtFolder/2020/github/syncHDD/syncHDD.py", line 173, in createPath
    os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/media/genericUser/5A48F86048F83BF7/2020.11.22/crtFolder/2020/udemy/react/code/section_12_adding_routing_someApp/addinRouting/src/hoc/Aux/'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

UPDATE: Already mentioned in the comments and realised this as well soon after that. the "e" is not defined. Not sure why that path cannot be created.

UPDATE: This works `os.makedirs('/media/genericUser/5A48F86048F83BF7/2020.11.22/crtFolder/2020/udemy/react/code/section_12_adding_routing_someApp/addinRouting/src/')` so the `/hoc/Aux` is the issue.

Questions:

1. why is that hoc/Aux causing issues?
2. why isn't the e defined in `except OSError as e:`

Comment: Your `except:` should raise otherwise your function returns without a return value so the caller gets `None` as the destination path.

Comment: Does your code work if you don’t put / on the end of the value passed to `makedirs()`? If you use `os.path.join()` you won’t have to manually code adding /

Comment: @barry makes sense. didn't see that and no . I get the same error without the "/"

Comment: Are there perhaps any special non-printing characters in that path name?

Comment: the issue seems to be '/hoc/Aux' but not much else. like ... that's the exact path and my username only contains plain letters and numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue.

`e` is a class so this `log(1,"createPath: Failed to create " + dest + " with error " + e,file)` fails.

correct is :

```
log(1,"createPath: Failed to create " + dest + " with error " + e.strerror,file)
```

not the only issue. turns out my code was not able to handle that failing so to fix that I made my function to return `''` if exception is hit. Now shutil still attemps to copy to `''` but it fails and outputs and error message. Still don't know why `/hoc/Aux` causes an issue. It can be copied fine to a different device. it's just this external HDD that has this issue.

Comment: Up to src, it's 130 characters and 9 folders deep. I would try on a shorted location, such as mounting the device directly on `/mnt`, and see if that helps